# Atomicity of Reads and Writes to Variables

Tags: java, atomic

I've just read a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729364/atomic-operations-and-multithreading), and read the most rated answer by 
@JB Nizet, and I got confused...
According to the answer, in the following code,

```
private int a=0;

public void foo(){
  int temp=35;
  a=28;
  a=temp;
}
```

`a=28;` is an atomic operation.

In some other questions and answers that I've read in Stackoverflow, the information was different, saying that `a=28;` is **not** an atomic operation, because first a read operation of the right operand should take place, then the write operation takes place, and each of these 2 operations is atomic, but the entire assignment is not (To be honest, this is how I thought it works).

And what about `a=temp;` ? Is it any different than `a=28;` in terms of atomicity?

By the way, I know about the need of volatile for double and long to make read/write to them atomic, just confused about what I wrote above.

Can someone plz elaborate on this?

Thanks..

Comment: You're confusing the *scope* of the word "operation". The assignment to `a` is atomic, because `a` is an `int`. Had it been a `long`, it wouldn't have been an atomic operation. That is all regardless of how the value to assign is obtained. You're right, the *statement* is not atomic, but the *assignment operation* is.

Comment: As an aside, in addition to atomicity it's good to be aware of *visibility* between threads. Fun examples here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787094/how-to-demonstrate-java-multithreading-visibility-problems

Comment: @Andreas, Thanks. 
I understood what you say, that the actual write to a variable is atomic.
It’s just that I see in so many documentations and books that something like a=temp; is atomic, so it confused me.
Can I say that a=temp; is not atomic in the sense that if threadA executes a=temp;  , between the read of temp and write to a, another threadB could interleave on a, and read the value of a, before it was written by threadA, hence making a=temp; not atomic by definition of atomicity?

Comment: @JamesJenkins You are correct, another thread could execute between read operation and write operation, so assignment *statement* is not atomic. Since "atomic" is usually about *operations*, you should make sure to clarify that you're talking about *statement* when saying it's not atomic, or people will misunderstand you, the way you've been misunderstanding what you've read.

Answer (score 6):

According to the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html):

> Reads and writes are atomic for reference variables and for most primitive variables (all types except long and double).

Since `a=28;` is a write into a primitive which isn't long or double, it's atomic.

However `a=temp` isn't atomic since it consists of two separate operations - the read from `temp` and the write to `int`. Each of these is atomic, but not their composition.

Comment: Thanks.
I’ve read the documentation, still got confused.
So you say that if I use a literal, like 28 in the example, no other thread could interleave on a=28; ? 
However, another thread could interleave on a=temp where between the read of temp and write to a, another thread could come in and read the value of a…
?